# C - Can I make a 2d array without specifying the size of each slot

Tags: c

In my homework, I have been asked to write a program and a part of it was to make a 2d array and get 10 names into it.
Now they didn't specify the size of each name, now my question is how do I make a 2d array without specifying each name size?
`char arr[10][?] = {0};`

Comment: Dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: If you haven't yet used pointers (comment below) you can use the same length for each and just leave the excess unused. `char arr[10][MAXLENG+1] = {0};`

Comment: Yes that is actually really smart! but how do I write it? like how do I remove those excess empty (or 0) "slots" ?

Comment: You don't: you just leave the memory unused after the `'\0'` string terminator at the end of each name.

Comment: A 2D array requires *both* indexes be specified. That can be provided through an initializer (e.g. `char array[][10] = { "my", "dog", "has", "fleas" };` or by explicit use of an integer constant. (e.g. `char array[10][10];`). Regardless which you use, the number of characters (columns) must be specified. (there are also uses of `'*'` specified in the C-standard for parameters not relevant here). Otherwise you will dynamically allocate memory - which results in a usable block of memory that can be indexed as a 2D array, but is not a technical 'array'.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't learned about pointers then the easiest method is Weather Vane's recommendation to decide on a maximum length for the name and use that for every subarray in your 2d array.

You do not need to "remove those excess empty (or 0) 'slots' " because when you write a string in c, or when you are using scanf or printf with strings, the strings are null-terminated.   This means when you put the name into the subarray, the name will probably already have a null termination (a value of 0) to signify the end of the string.  Every value after that null termination is ignored when working with functions that deal with null-terminated strings.

For example.

```
char name[] = "Bob";
```

is actually equivalent to doing either of these:

```
char name[] = { 'B', 'o', 'b', '\0'};  //'\0' is a null termination
char name[] = {0x42, 0x6F, 0x62, 0x0}; // ascii hex codes, '\0' translates to 0x0
```

(it doesn't matter how big name[] is if the string is null-terminated and the functions you are using know that).
You can manually insert a null termination if for some reason when you put in the name it doesn't already have it.